# Set product shipping class based on metadata in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, metadata, product

I'm trying to write a specific function that allow to change automatically  the product shipping class when a WooCommerce custom field is set with a specific value.

Please find below the screenshot about the custom fields

[image]

---

This is the code I had thought of but obviously it doesn't work.

```
function woo_on_product_save( $post_id ) {
    $title = $product->get_meta( 'meta_easyfatt_libero_1' );
    if ( $title = 'Trenta' ) {
        $shipping_class_id = 1182;
    }

    $product = wc_get_product( $post_id );
    $product->set_shipping_class_id( $shipping_class_id );
    $product->save();
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_process_product_meta', 'woo_on_product_save', 100 );
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some minor mistakes

- You use `$product->get_meta(..` while `$product` is not defined
- The comparison operator in an if statement is `==`, not `=`
- Use `woocommerce_admin_process_product_object` to save instead of the outdated `woocommerce_process_product_meta` hook

So you get:

```php
// Save
function action_woocommerce_admin_process_product_object( $product ) {
    // Get meta
    $title = $product->get_meta( 'meta_easyfatt_libero_1' );
    
    if ( $title == 'Trenta' ) {
        // The targeted shipping class ID to be set for the product
        $shipping_class_id = 1182;

        // Set the shipping class ID 
        $product->set_shipping_class_id( $shipping_class_id );
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_admin_process_product_object', 'action_woocommerce_admin_process_product_object', 10, 1 );
```

Comment: Hi @7uc1f3r . This code worked perfectly for me but now i have another need. Since updating the shipping class depends on saving the product, is there a way to automatically save / update all products on woocommerce, perhaps at a certain time once a day? Maybe to avoid overloads you could save / update a certain number of products every hour? I'll be really gratefull if you can help with this too

Comment: @Deegita Either you can apply something like used in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70146352/11987538) (**the last part**), it's for orders, but would be the same for products. Basically, an x ​​number of products are automatically updated every time when a website visitor views a page. However, a [cronjob](https://www.businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-custom-cron-job/) seems more appropriate. But if you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context.